# Symfony\Console DialogHelper not found, when running `propel init`

Tags: php, symfony, fatal-error, propel

I'm getting this error, when running `php propel init`:

```
$ php propel init

Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rmanager/api/vendor/propel/propel/src/Propel/Generator/Command/Helper/DialogHelper.php on line 8
```

Why the class isn't found? Is it a bug?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You can switch it to use `Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper`. Dialog helper was deprecated and later removed.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue about precisely this error open at https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/1080, for which [a fix](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/commit/31ae3a6f83dbdc90fee09a95646bec27a8d57457) has already been merged into Propel's master branch.

As of the moment I'm writing this answer, it's not yet part of any tagged release, but if you use the current master version of Propel it will probably fix your error.